# Problem Creating a Textbox on PowerPoint Addin Slide Using JavaScript API

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins, powerpoint-web-addins

I am trying to create a PowerPoint Addin and would like to dynamically create and format a textbox on an active slide when a button is clicked. I have done a lot of research and debugging but I am not sure why my code is not creating the textbox. I am using PowerPoint JavaScript API on VS Code Here is my sample code

```
function createDynamicTextBox() {
// Get the active slide
Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(Office.CoercionType.SlideRange, function (result) {
  if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
    // Get the first slide
    var slide = result.value.slides[0];

    // Create a text box
    var textBox = slide.shapes.addTextbox(Office.CoercionType.Text, 100, 100, 200, 50);

    // Set properties of the text box
    textBox.textFrame.textRange.text = "Dynamic Text Box";
    textBox.textFrame.textRange.font.size = 14;

    // You can further customize the properties as needed
  } else {
   console.error("Error getting selected data: " + result.error.message);
  }
});
```

The problem is with the shapes object which on debug returns 'undefined'. I am wondering whether it is possible to achieve what I would like.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to call the `await context.sync();` when you would like to apply your changes.

Be aware, there is an active issue with PowerPoint shapes, see [Powerpoint ScriptLab Insert shape, line and text box sample does not work on web; works fine on desktop](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/2699) for more information.